# Using something similar to Google Earth as a view in my application

Tags: windows, c#, gui, 3d

I would like to have a 3D GUI view in my application that shows the earth and objects located on and around the earth, which my application defines. I would also like the ability to customize the  view so that the user can control these objects in the view itself. It would be great if I can place objects by specifying a latitude and longitude and things like that. I'm using C# and WPF so ideally it would be either .NET library that works with WPF, or a native library.

I searched for whether Google offers a library I can use. They do, but it's WebGL based and involves having to integrate a Javascript API with C# https://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/ .

That seems pretty ugly to integrate in my application. Is there anything else I can use?

Comment: Do you care about license and price?

Comment: Ideally it would be free and open-source. If I couldn't find a good one, then just free (as in beer) is good. Otherwise, something commercial is a valid option provided it has good documentation and support

Comment: NASA WorldWind used to have a neat C# port somewhere on SourceForge...